# Compute $E(\sqrt{X+Y})$ given that $X,Y$ are iid

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, expected-value

Compute $E(\sqrt{X+Y})$ given that $X,Y$ are iid.

Assume $X,Y$ are iid both having an Exp($\lambda=1)$ distribution.

Although this is the only information provided in the question, I know that since they are independent, then the joint distribution must be $$f_{X,Y}(X,Y)=e^{-x} e^{-y}$$

Then we must integrate:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}e^{-y}(x+y)^{1/2}dxdy=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-y}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}(x+y)^{1/2}dxdy$$

This integral seems complicated to evaluate. I tried it out and it seems like I'll have to do parts atleast twice. Wolfram says the answer is $1.32934$ and I have $1.33$ as one of the options to this question.

I want to know if there's an easier way to evaluate this. Do I even need the integral? Or perhaps is there some trick to get the answer with this integral?

Comment: How so? There's a square root surrounding it

Comment: One thing that might be worth committing to memory is that the sum of $n$ IID exponentials (with the same rate) is Gamma(n)-distributed. So, here the PDF for $Z=X+Y$ is $f(z) = z e^{-z}$ so the answer is $\int_0^\infty z^{3/2} e^{-z}dz.$ In general, it's probably a good approach to first find the PDF of $Z=X+Y$ using a standard approach and then calculate $E(\sqrt{Z}).$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of getting the integral slightly faster is to see that everything is in terms of $x+y$ only.

So let $z=x+y$, which ranges from $0$ to $\infty$, and then given $z$ we have $x$ ranges from $0$ to $z$. The Jacobian for this is just $1$.

Then the double integral becomes
$$
\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^ze^{-z}z^{\frac{1}{2}}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}z=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-z}z^{\frac{3}{2}}\,\mathrm{d}z=\Gamma\left(\frac{5}{2}\right)=\frac{3\sqrt{\pi}}{4}$$

Comment: So this is $u$ substitution. If we let $u=x+y$, then the inner integral goes from $$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}(x+y)^{1/2}dx\to\int_{y}^{\infty}e^{y-u}u^{1/2}du$$. I'm not sure how you get the $z$ on top. Or am I missing something?

Comment: The analogue of $u$ substitution in multiple integrals is to define $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ as your new coordinates. The factor to scale the integral is the Jacobian, which is the determinant of the matrix of partial derivatives. Similarly to $u$ substitution in a definite integral, you also need to re-express the limits of integration in the new coordinates. For 2D, it is best to draw a diagram and see what is going on.

Comment: In this particular case, $z=x+y$ and $x=x$. The original region is the quadrant $x\geq0$, $y\geq0$. Within this region, $x+y$ goes from $0$ to $\infty$. To see what the $x$ range is, consider fixing $z=x+y$. This is the diagonal line $y=z-x$, which fits in the quadrant as long as $0\leq x\leq z$, which is therefore the limits for the inner integral.